# Rails 4 my .bashrc file does not reflect latest ruby version

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have upgraded to Rails 4 and have the following versions installed (see below). The problem is that my .bashrc file still have references to ruby-1.9.2. Is this a problem and how do I correct this?

```
$ rvm list
rvm rubies
   ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0
```

.bashrc
PATH="/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/francoisvdhoven/.rvm/bin:/Users/francoisvdhoven/.rvm/bin/npm:/Users/francoisvdhoven/.rvm/bin:/bin:/Users/francoisvdhoven/.rvm/bin/node:/Users/francoisvdhoven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin:/Users/francoisvdhoven/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320@global/bin:/Users/francoisvdhoven/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin"

Thanks for your help!
Francois

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok to remove these specific paths from your .bashrc file.

A typical rvm installation should not impact your .bashrc beyond the following line in it:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Also, your .bash_profile should only have this one line in it:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

With these entries, ruby locations in your $PATH variable will be appropriately set on-the-fly when you use rvm to select which ruby you wish to work with... thereby removing any need to hard-set any ruby paths explicitly in your .bashrc file.